# Hacer que un campo sea Id_ a la hora de crear un mapping en elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Quiero indezar un monton de documentos en elasticsearch.
Para ello creao un mapping de un indice en elasticsearch y luego los indexo.

Pero cada vez que indexo un documento, me genera un Id_ que no es el que necesito.

```
PUT prueba/_mapping
    {
        "properties" : 
      {
        "name" : 
        {
          "type" : "text",
              "analyzer": "spanish"
        },

        "email" : 
        {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : 
          {
            "keyword" : 
            {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "no_" : 
        {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : 
          {
            "keyword" : 
            {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
```

}

Pero cuando indexo documentos me crea un campo Id_ que no tiene nada que ver con ninguno de estos.

Hay manera de indicar en el mapping al crearlo que quiero que el campo "no_" sea el Id del documento que se indexa?

Answer (score 0):

En el API de Eelasticsearch a la hora de crear documentos tienes varias maneras de hacerlo. Echále un ojo a la documentación de [Index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html)

Encontrarás que el request lo puedes hacer de las siguientes maneras:

> PUT /indice/_doc/<_id>

> POST /indice/_doc/

> PUT /indice/_create/<_id>

> POST /indice/_create/<_id>

Supongo que tu estas indexando tus documentos con `POST prueba/_doc {}` si quieres cambiar el `_id` por uno que tu conozcas puedes o bien usar `PUT prueba/_doc/{id_que_tu_quieras}` o bien usar el [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) para copiar el valor de `no_` a `_id`